# order by column exist in another table and remove redundant rows

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

i work with laravel and MySQL and i have 2 tables: **products** and **variations**

Each product has many variations and each variation has price column.

i want to order products by price so joined tables.

But there was a problem. a products with 3 variation appeared at three record

```
products | price
----------------
1        | 10
1        | 11
2        | 21
2        | 22
2        | 23
```

So I grouped results with `GROUP BY variations.product_id`.

```
products | price
----------------
1        | 11
2        | 23
```

But still i have 1 problem! i need just ONE product with LOWEST price.

Does anyone have an idea?

---

laravel code:

```
$this->builder->join('variations', 'variations.product_id',
              '=',
              'products.id')
              ->select('products.*')
              ->groupBy('variations.product_id')
              ->orderBy('variations.discounted_price', 'Desc');
```

---

produced SQL code

```
select `products`.* from `products` inner join `variations` 
on `variations`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
group by `variations`.`product_id` order by `variations`.`discounted_price`
```

Comment: Please show us the full query you have tried.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want access to the all columns in the record, do not aggregate. Instead, you can use a correlated subquery to filter in only the record with the lowest price.

```
SELECT p.*, v.`discounted_price`
FROM `products` p
INNER JOIN `variations` v ON v.`product_id` = p.`id` 
WHERE p.`category_id` = 14
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM `variations` v1 
    WHERE 
        v1.`product_id` = v.`product_id` 
        AND v1.`discounted_price` < v.`discounted_price`
)
```

NB : I added table aliases to the query to make it more readable. Also in this expression the second condition is redondant, so I removed it.

```
p.`category_id` = 14 and p.`category_id` is not null
```

---

With MySQL 8.0, you can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to do the filtering part more efficiently :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.*, 
        v.`discounted_price`,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v.`product_id` ORDER BY v.`discounted_price`) rn
    FROM `products` p
    INNER JOIN `variations` v on v.`product_id` = p.`id` 
    WHERE p.`category_id` = 14
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: i run your first code and it's fetch all variation for each products.

Comment: @AbolfazlB : ahh, I mixed columns `varations.product_id` and `products.id`. I just updated the queries, please let me know if it produces the expected output now.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a the group function `MIN()` to accomplish this

I'm making assumptions about your query to illustrate this.

```
SELECT `products`.`id`,MIN(`variations`.`price`) AS `price`
FROM `products`
JOIN `variations` on `variations`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
```

if you need just ONE just add `ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1`

Edit: based on your code, try

```
$this->builder->join('variations', 'variations.product_id',
          '=',
          'products.id')
          ->select('products.*')
          ->groupBy('variations.product_id')
          ->orderBy('variations.discounted_price', 'Asc')
          ->first();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not work! please note that i don't want fetch 1 row. i want to fetch one row for any product

Comment: hmm are you forgetting to request the right 'price' column? you're sorting on `variations.discounted_price` but are only requesting fields from the `products` table. have you tried adding `variations.discounted_price` to your select statement?